# Inno Setup gets launched in 32 bit even after specifying ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode

Tags: inno-setup

I am running an installer generated using InnoSetup on 64 bit Windows OS (Windows Server 2012 R2) installation with `ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64` and `ArchitecturesAllowed=x64` but I still see that the process gets launched in 32 bit mode. Am I missing some other basic setting ?

**OS Details :**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users>wmic OS get OSArchitecture
OSArchitecture
64-bit

C:\Users>echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%
AMD64

C:\Users>systeminfo | findstr /I type:
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
System Type:               x64-based PC

C:\Users>
```

**Inno Setup :**
[image]

**Task Manager :**
This is what Task Manager shows (I have masked out some names etc)
[image]

**Answer :**
Based on comments section, Inno Setup always produces a 32 bit installer executable. There is no mechanism to produce a 64 bit installer. I was mis-interpreting the documentation.

Comment: As long as the installer inserts the files to the right place, what bitness is used by its executable does not matter.

Comment: If things were that simple and straightforward, there would have been no need to have a notion of a 32-bit vs 64-bit install mode

Comment: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=64bitlimitations But whatever has been documented. If you do hit a more specific issue, say it.

Comment: Refer to : "Install Mode: 32-bit vs. 64-bit"
"64-bit mode is selected if the user is running a 64-bit version of Windows and the system's processor architecture is included in the value of the ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode [Setup] section directive. Otherwise, 32-bit mode is used."

What's documented is not happening.

Comment: Well, it depends on which line you are reading. "Inno Setup is a 32-bit application" explains why it is a 32 bit process you see. And then in "64 bit mode", the setup process disables WOW64 redirection and pretends itself to be a 64 bit process.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean. I have been thinking WRT another application that itself is a 32 bit application where it allows me to generate a 32 bit or 64 bi binary binary based on target settings. I have been thinking on similar lines -- that "Inno Setup" application itself is a 32 bit software but will allow me to generate an installer executable that can be either a 32 bit binary or a 64 bit binary. Maybe TLama or Martin Prikryl can confirm if the latter is the case or else this question is meaningless (with maybe some scope for improving the Inno documentation) ?

Comment: @LexLi is completely right!

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Closing the question.

Comment: It's your question. So you can delete it straight away. --- Or @LexLi can post a proper answer. I do not think that your question is that pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inno Setup started to support 64 bit installation long before Delphi supports 64 bit executable generation. Therefore, its core executable is 32 bit, and executes as a 32 bit process:

> Inno Setup is a 32-bit application

To install files to 64 bit Windows folders while remaining a 32 bit process, it has to disable WOW64 redirection:

> Setup temporarily disables WOW64 file system redirection when files/directories are accessed by those sections.

That explains what you observed.

Quotes can be found in the official article:
http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=64bitlimitations

Answer (score 3):

The installer that Inno Setup creates is always 32-bit.

Unfortunately this means that if your application is 64-bit and the environment that someone is installing to only supports 64-bit then it won't work. This can happen, for example, when running under Wine when only 64-bit is supported. This appears to be the case for CentOS's implementation of Wine. Therefore all Inno Setup installations will fail (even for 64-bit programs) because it can't run 32-bit programs. I just became aware of this situation myself thanks to one of my customers.

Update: See the Notes on EPEL section here: [CentOS - Notes on EPEL 7](https://wiki.winehq.org/CentOS/RHEL#Notes_on_EPEL_7)